# Fixing brick cracks above garage door

Tags: brick, siding, beam, garage-door

My house had foundation issues several times which is fixed now and after every fix we get more brick cracks above the garage door. Some people say that foundation has nothing to do with those cracks and it happens because the beam above garage door bends down and it can fall if I don'replace it. Siding guys told me that it won't fall, but they can secure the angular beam screwing it to the wood. And it can all be patched.

1. Is it safe just to disassemble some parts of that wall (a few bricks from each side) and patch it?
2. Should I replace the beam or do something with it?
3. Any advices how it can be fixed?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVNxt.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/55I4l.jpg

Comment: Can't tell from the picture what the bricks are resting on.  Is there an L-shaped lintel (usually metal, steel or iron?) above the garage door openings, that the bricks rest on?

Comment: Yes. There is one metal lintel

Comment: I uploaded the picture to the question

Comment: If the beam (lintel) above the garage door is really bending, then that indicates to me that it was undersized to begin with.  I don't think trying to fasten it to the wooden header that's also above the garage door opening is a viable fix.

Comment: And from the second picture, it looks like the bricks may not be bearing on the lintel properly.  There appears to be a significant amount of brick overhang beyond (outside of) the lintel, though it's hard to ascertain the scale of things from the picture.

Comment: Lintel is bent about 0.1 inch in the middle. Not sure how bad is that. The house is about 26 years old

Answer (score 1):

While not an answer, this is the only way I can post a picture.

Here is what a properly installed lintel looks like, at least in my mind.  Note that the bricks overhang the lintel by a tiny (1/4"?) bit.

[image]